# member variables in JUnit tests

Tags: java, junit

i came across something interesting while running some unit tests. i have the following method:

```
private void createSchemaIfNecessary() throws SQLException, IOException{
    if(!schemaExists){
         try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection(); Statement statement = connection.createStatement();) {
             statement.execute(getSQLByFileName(GOLF_COURSE_TABLE_CREATION_SCRIPT));
             statement.execute(getSQLByFileName(GOLF_COURSE_HOLE_TABLE_CREATION_SCRIPT));
             connection.commit();
             schemaExists = true;
         }
    }
}
```

each unit test calls this method to determine whether or not to create the tables. the `schemaExists` variable is a member variable. i noticed that as each test was running, there were cases where even after hitting the `schemaExists = true;` line, the next time the method was called, `schemaExists` evaluated to false. i then made the variable static, and that fixed the problem.

As the individual unit tests are running, don't they all run within the context of a single instance of the unit test class?

Comment: I think the right approach is to setup (create and populate the tables with the required data for a particular test) and discard everything after that. With your approach, you might run into a race condition for some tests if they run concurrently (as they should), unless you are calling `createSchemaIfNecessary` within the method annotated with `@BeforeClass` – something impossible in your case since your method is not `static`...yet.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to assume `schemaExists` is a non-static member of your test class.

Before invoking a test method (annotated `@Test`), junit (by default) creates a new instance of your test class ([More detail here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-instance-lifecycle)).

Thus, any non-static class member will be initialized as per defined in the class If not explicitly initialized, then they'll be set to their defaults, so if  `schemaExists` is a `boolean` (primitive) then `false`.

I'd suggest that what you want to do if you want to setup something for all tests to share is create a `@BeforeClass` static method to initialize a static property.

- This will ensure it's run only once for the given test class, before any test methods are run
- It's very clear to others reading your code what the intention was for the method

Here's an example with the DB schema initialization code in your OP:

```
@BeforeClass 
public static void setupDBOnce() {
   Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection(); 
   Statement statement = connection.createStatement();  
   statement.execute(getSQLByFileName(GOLF_COURSE_TABLE_CREATION_SCRIPT));
   statement.execute(getSQLByFileName(GOLF_COURSE_HOLE_TABLE_CREATION_SCRIPT));
   connection.commit();
 }
```

If for some reason you don't want this behavior (one instance per test method run) [you can do any of these](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-instance-lifecycle-changing-default):

- Annotate your class with `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)`
- Pass the following VM arg: `-Djunit.jupiter.testinstance.lifecycle.default=per_class`
- Create or add to an existing property file named `junit-platform.properties` found in the source root of the class path the entry: `junit.jupiter.testinstance.lifecycle.default = per_class`

If you do override the default, one note worth remembering from the docs:

> When using this mode, a new test instance will be created once per test class. Thus, if your test methods rely on state stored in instance variables, you may need to reset that state in @BeforeEach or @AfterEach methods.

Comment: i was going to use BeforeClass, the issue is that I have autowired  dependencies that are injected by spring which the setup method relies on, and I can't make those static

Comment: @user1154644 Ah, ok, then see my update -- added a way to force Junit to use the same instance (instead of the default one-per-test-method)

Comment: @user1154644 did any of the methods to change the lifecycle work?